# Using LINEST to extract polynomial coefficients of higher order (>3) in Excel for Mac 2019 (16.44)

Tags: excel, macos

We have a data set of x and y values in a Excel sheet and want to extract the polynomial coefficients for a polynomial fit of oder >3.

How do you do this? I tried all the methods suggested on the web & YouTube.
None of them worked.

Its often suggested to use

```
=LINEST(YDATA,XDATA^{1,2,3}) or LINEST(YDATA;XDATA^{1;2;3})
```

This doesnt work in Excel 16.44 (Office 2019) on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write down the steps involved for people in the future, so they save themselves some headache.

(1) First name 3 datasets:

1. XDATA
2. YDATA
3. COEFFS

by highlighting the columns and hitting **⌘/command+fn+F3** and giving them some names.
For the COEFFS you want cells showing 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

(2) Select a new ROW of 5 cells (N+1)

Click **control+U** and then type

```
=LINEST(XDATA;YDATA^COEFFS)
```

to insert an array on Mac you need to hit **Control+Shift+Return/Enter**.

Then you will have an row with the coefficients of a polynomial fit of N'th order.

First cell is for the Nth polynomial and the last cell is the constant.